# scraping an iframe with beautifulsoup and python

Tags: beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape the following page:

https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/sentiment/

more exactly, the numbers in the chart. for example, the number 74,19 % in the green bar next to the aud/usd text. i have inspected the elements and found out that the tag for this number is span. but the following code does not return this or any other number in the chart:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/sentiment/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
data = soup('span')
print(data)
```

Comment: Here is the source of that information, it might just be easier to get it here: https://freeserv.dukascopy.com

Comment: i can't find anything useful there :(

Answer (score 1):

So if you incorporate selenium with beautiful soup, you will get all the abilities of selenium to scrape iframes.

try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(bond_iframe)
bond_source = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(bond_source,"html.parser")

for div in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'qs-note-panel'}):
print div
```

The `for` loop would be which div tag you are searching for